# Como imprimir la consonante de un texto

Tags: c#

Tengo este código en c# el cual me imprime la cantidad de consonantes que hay en la frase que se ingreso,mi duda es como imprimir que consonante es.

**EJEMPLO**

**gonzalez**

//salida

cantidad de consonantes: 1

**la consonante es: n**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Escriba una frase: ");
        string frase = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de consonantes en {0}"+CuentaConsonante(frase) );
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int CuentaConsonante(string frase)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        char c;
        foreach (char v in frase)
        {
            c = Char.ToLower(v);
            if (c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'f' || c == 'g'|| c == 'h'|| c == 'n')
                contador++;

        }
        return contador;
    }
```

Comment: Te he añadido una respuesta, pero creo que la salida esperada que pones no es correcta. `gonzalez` tiene una `g` y una `n`, con lo que la salida deben ser ambas consonantes, no solo la `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a exponer una solución muy sencilla usando LINQ:

```
char[] consonantes = new char[] { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'n' };

string inputstring = "gonzalezn";
var conson = inputstring.ToLower().Where(x => consonantes.Contains(x)).GroupBy(x=> x);

foreach (var cons in conson)
{
    Console.WriteLine("la consonante {0} se repite {1} veces", cons.Key, cons.Count());
}

Console.WriteLine("total de consonantes diferentes encontradas: {0}", conson.Count());
Console.WriteLine("total de consonantes encontradas: {0}", conson.SelectMany(x => x).Count());
```

Lo que hacemos es definir primero un array con los caracteres que queremos buscar. Posteriormente, usando `Where` buscamos todos los caracteres de la cadena de entrada que estén incluidos en el array de consonantes, y agrupamos ya que pueden estar repetidos.

Por último, recorremos los resultados e imprimimos el caracter y el numero de veces que se ha encontrado.

El código anterior tiene la siguiente salida, dado `gonzalezn` como entrada:

```
la consonante g se repite 1 veces
la consonante n se repite 2 veces
total de consonantes diferentes encontradas: 2
total de consonantes encontradas: 3
```

**Edit**

Si en realidad quieres contar todas las consonantes, y no solo las que pones en tu ejemplo, lo que debes hacer cambiar el array de consonantes por uno de vocales, y usar [`Char.IsLetter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=netframework-4.7.2) para comprobar por un lado si el caracter es un letra, y por otro si no es una vocal:

```
char[] vocales = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
var conson = inputstring.ToLower().Where(x => Char.IsLetter(x) && !vocales.Contains(x)).GroupBy(x=> x);
```

El resultado del código modificando esa linea es el siguiente (usando `gonzalez` como entrada:

```
la consonante g se repite 1 veces
la consonante n se repite 1 veces
la consonante z se repite 2 veces
la consonante l se repite 1 veces
total de consonantes diferentes encontradas: 4
total de consonantes encontradas: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te indica @Pikoh lo más sencillo es usar LinQ, aunque no sé si entendí bien la pregunta, pero para no poner las 22 consonantes yo lo haría con las vocales y un "where not in "
de la siguiente manera:

```
            char[] consonantes = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

            string inputstring = "gonzalezn";
            var conson = inputstring.ToLower().Where(x => !consonantes.Contains(x)).GroupBy(x => x);

            foreach (var cons in conson) {
                Console.WriteLine("la consonante {0} se repite {1} veces", cons.Key, cons.Count());
            }
```

Comment: La pregunta en ese sentido no esta clara, por eso yo respondí con las consonantes que el había usado en su código. De todas maneras, ten en cuenta que con esta solución, caracteres como los signos de puntuación por ejemplo, se sumarían como consonantes.

Comment: Puedes mirar en mi respuesta como lo solucionaría yo de una forma bastante sencilla :)

Comment: Pikoh gracias por la ayuda ya esta solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Debe reemplazar esta línea:

```
Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de consonantes en {0}"+CuentaConsonante(frase) );
```

por esta :

```
Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de consonantes en {0}" , CuentaConsonante(frase));
```

Comment: pero me imprime lo mismo,me imprime la cantidad y quiero saber que consonate es  asi **gonzalez** la consonate es n